# How to rewrite links to images from old site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am trying to move my old page from WolfCMS to WordPress. My all links to images looks like:

`<img src="/public/images/my_image.jpg" />` ..and in old CMS links like that was automatically converted to: 
`http://my_domain_name/public/images/my_image.jpg`

Can I get the same result in WordPress?
Or maybe the easiest way will be to do it via **mod_rewrite**, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: That's not a feature of your CMS, a link like that is always relative to the domain you're already on.

Comment: yes but on my dev installation I have a domain and folder, like localhost/wordpress (images are in localhost/wordpress/public/...) - and at the moments links like that doesn't work for me, but I need to see images on dev installation before I public a final website. Any idea, how to do that?